# Let $K$ be a compact metric spaces. Prove that $C(K)$ is a Banach space when given the supremum norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact metric spaces. 
    Prove that $C(K)$ is a Banach space when given the supremum norm.

My attempt:

I want to use the Cauchy Summability Criteria to prove it.  The Cauchy Summability criteria states that a normed space $X$ is complete if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x_n\| <\infty$ implies that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n$ converges in $X $.

Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions in $C(K)$ and assume that $$M = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|f_n\|_{\infty} < \infty.$$
    We wish to show that there exists $f \in C(K)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ converges to $f.$

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and each $x \in K,$ we have $|f_n(x)| \leq \| f_n\|.$
    Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|f_n\|_{\infty} < \infty,$ by Weierstrass M-test, $f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ exists.

It remains to show that $f \in C(K).$ I do not know how to show it.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The fact that $K$ is compact gives that the $f_n$s are uniformly continuous, which should make you conclude.

Comment: What is the Cauchy summability criteria? You need to prove that the seq. converge to a continuous function.

Comment: @Olba12: i have included the criteria in my post.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

If $g$ denotes the limit of the seq. $(g_n)_n$. Then

$$
|g(x)-g(y)| \leq |g(x) - g_k(x)| + | g_k(x) - g_k(y)| + |g_k(y) - g(y)|.
$$

Comment: But I do not have $f_k $. Instead, I have $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n.$

Comment: Well, then let $g_k = \sum_{n=0}^{k} f_n$. @Idonknow

Comment: Do you see how the limit is continuous now? @Idonknow

Comment: Yes, I know why the limit is continuous.